# Go back to original branch after git stash

Tags: git, git-stash

I wanted to check a previous commit.

I am in brach  `mybranch` where I had a few changes in a file, that's why I did  `git stash` first.

Then,

`git checkout previouscommit`

I ran the code, made a few changes that I don't want to save.

Now, how can I go back to `mybranch`?

1)  I don't want to keep the changes I made in `previouscommit`.

2) I want to go back to `mybranch`

I know I have to do  a `git stash pop` but I am not sure at what point. Before, or after checking `mybranch`? (Also I can't right now because I have done some changes as I said to a file that I don't want to keep and I am not sure how to force to go back to `mybranch`.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following sequence of commands:

```
git checkout .
git checkout -
git stash pop
```

The first one throws out the changes you've made on `previouscommit`, the second returns you to the previously checked out commit/branch, the last one restores the changes you've stashed.

You can use `git checkout mybranch` instead of the second command.

Comment: I noticed one thing though..At the `mybranch` the changes I have made to one file aren't there..Weird..I have done first `git stash` and I followed your directions.

Comment: @George You've done `git stash` *before* you've checked out the `previouscommit`, correct? In this case the changes you made to tracked files at `mybranch` should all be in the stash and be re-applied once you do `git stash pop`. It's really strange if that's not the case.

Comment: :yes,I did first `git stash` , then checkout to previouscommit.Anyway,thankfully I remember the changes I had done but very weird!

Answer (score 0):

- At first, if you don't want to keep the latest changes you can revert them by: `git reset --hard`
- Then you can checkout your branch using `git checkout mybranch`
- And then you need to do `git stash pop`

Answer (score 0):

I hope this help someone.
I used git stash and had a hard time going back to the point where i was before using that command.

1- I used `git stash list` it retrieved the last commit code and message before the stash command.

2- I grabbed the retrieved code and used `git checkout <commit code>`.

Answer (score -1):

Just do a

```
git reset --hard mybranch
git stash pop
```